# Delete Microsoft OneDrive credentials from W10 PC

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, onedrive, credentials-manager

Imagine u once made this unforgivable mistake of getting in touch with Microsoft ... OneDrive. Is there any chance to reverse it?

How to delete your Microsoft OneDrive credentials permanently from your PC? So that a new OneDrive installation does not automatically log in to your OneDrive account and start syncing you files?

I searched the web and tried (in different orders, all at once, ...):

1. Open the OneDrive settings and click "Unlink this PC" (it works until the next restart of W10)
2. Uninstall OneDrive
3. Delete **all** credentials in the Windows credential manager
4. Deleted **all** credential via the command prompt (run as administrator):

- cmdkey /list
- cmdkey /delete:targetname

5. Deleted the "C:\Users...\OneDrive" folder
6. Searched my entire computer and deleted everything with the name OneDrive in it
7. Delted Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity\Identities
8. Delted HKCU\Software\Microsoft\OneDrive\Accounts(businessUwant2remove)
9. Signed out from my M. Office account and M. Teams account
10. Tried to delete my Microsoft Account

- Follow the Microsoft Instruction: "Select the Start  button, and then select Settings  > Accounts  > Email & accounts . Under Accounts used by other apps, select the account you want to remove, and then select Remove." However, there is no "Remove" button, but just "Manage".
- Go to the Delete your Microsoft Account website (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=523898) and follow a lengthy procedure to delete my account.

Still, if I download OneDrive, reinstall it, it automatically logs in to my account and starts syncing files.

I also cannot add any other account to my OneDrive (e.g. my work related account) "Sorry, OneDrive can't add your folder right now". My Office 365 runs on my work related account, which I would (if any) link also to my OneDrive.

Any other idea how to end this enforced marriage?

Comment: One Drive is part of Office 365 which I use. I do not put any files in One Drive - I keep my files elsewhere on the computer. So One Drive just syncs nothing. This works for me.

Comment: My Office 365 runs on a different account (see edits above).

Comment: Copy the One Drive files to another non One Drive location and delete all files (not Folders) in One Drive and let it sync nothing forever.